# Заменить несколько файлов разом на сотне сайтов

Tags: ssh, isp

Есть сотня сайтов, необходимо в каждом из них заменить (перезаписать) 2-3 файла находящихся в разных папках.
Все файлы одинаковые.
Можно ли разом заменить файлы на всех сайтах с помощью ssh или isp?
Подскажите как?

Выделение в isp всех сайтов и попытка разархивировать в них архив с файлами для замены - не увенчалась успехом.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под **isp**?

Comment: ISPmanager, ssh если выделить все сайты и перетащить на выделенное файлы для замены, то файлы заменятся в одной папке (сайт). Думал это просто сделать, оказалось нет   :(